# Need to determine what values my Fourier Series converges to and on what intervals it does so

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, sturm-liouville

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $f(x) = 1$ for $0 < x < 1$. Write a generalized Fourier series for $f(x)$ in terms of the eigenfunctions of the following Sturm-Liouville problem. Discuss the convergence of this series:
>
> $\begin{matrix}-u^{\prime}{\prime}(x) = \mu u(x) \\ u(0) = u^{\prime}(1)=0 \end{matrix}$

What I've done thus far:

I have found the eigenvalues of this Sturm-Liouville problem to be $\displaystyle \mu_{n}= \left(\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{2} \right)^{2}$, and the eigenfunctions to be $\displaystyle u_{n}(x)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{2} \right)x$, $n = 1,2,\cdots$.

Now, since the eigenfunctions for a complete orthogonal set on $[0,1]$, we can expand $f(x) = 1$ as $\displaystyle f(x) = 1 \sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}\sin\left( \frac{\pi(2n-1)}{2}\right)\pi x$, where $\displaystyle b_{n} = \frac{2}{1}\int_{0}^{1} 1 \cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi (2n-1)}{2} \right)x dx = -\frac{4}{\pi(2n-1)}\left[\cos \left(\frac{\pi(2n-1)x}{2} \right) \right]_{0}^{1} = -\frac{4}{\pi(2n-1)}\left[\cos\left(\pi n - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) - 1 \right] = -\frac{4}{\pi(2n-1)}\left[\cos(\pi n)\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right)+ \sin(\pi n) \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{1}\right) - 1 \right] = \frac{4}{\pi(2n-1)}$.

So, $\displaystyle f(x) = 1 \sim \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)^{-1}\sin \left(\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{2} \right)x$.

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to the help of an extremely patient person who answered a similar question of mine here on MSE, I have come up with the following solution, which I would like someone to take a look at, and tell me if it's correct. If it's not, what can I do to fix it?  Thank you! :)

> $\displaystyle \sin \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right) \pi x$ has a period of $4$, since $\displaystyle \begin{align}\sin\left( \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi \left( x + 4 \right)\right) \\= \sin \left( \left( n-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\pi x + 4 \pi \right) \right) \\= \sin \left( \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x\right) + \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) 4 \pi) \\= \sin\left[\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x \right]\cos \left[\left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)4 \pi \right] + \cos \left[\left(n - \frac{1}{2} \right)\pi x\right]\sin \left[\left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)4 \pi \right] \\= \sin\left[\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x \right]\cos \left[\left( 2n -1 \right)2 \pi \right] + \cos \left[\left(n - \frac{1}{2} \right)\pi x\right]\sin \left[\left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)4 \pi \right] \\ = \sin\left[ \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x \right](1) = \cos \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x \right](0) \\ = \sin \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x \right]\end{align} $.
>
> Also,
>
> $\displaystyle \begin{align} \sin\left[ \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x \right] \\ = \sin\left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi (x + 1 - 1)\right] \\ = \sin \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \left[(x+1) \pi - \pi \right]\right] \\ = \sin\left[ \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right) (x+1) \pi - \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right] \\ = \sin \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)(x+1) \pi \right] \cos\left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right]  \\- \cos\left[\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)(x+1)\pi\right]\sin \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi \right] \\ = \sin \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) (x+1) \pi \right] (-1) - \cos \left[\left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)(x+1)\pi\right](0) \\ = -\sin \left[\left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)(x+1)\pi\right] \end{align}$
>
> Therefore, for $x \in (-1,0)$, $\displaystyle \sin \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) (x+1) \pi \right] = - \sin\left[ \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x \right]$.
>
> And so, for $x \in (-1,0)$, $\displaystyle f(x) = 1 \sim \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)^{-1}\sin \left[ \left( n-\frac{1}{2} \right) \pi x \right] \\ \displaystyle = -\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)^{-1}\sin \left[ \left( n-\frac{1}{2} \right) \pi (x+1) \right]$.
>
> Hence, for $x \in (-1,0)$, we have $\displaystyle -1 \sim \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n-1)^{-1}\sin \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi (x+1)\right]$, and putting everything together, we see that
>
> $\displaystyle \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n-1)^{-1}\sin \left[\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x \right] = \begin{cases} 1, & x\in (0,1)\\ -1, & x \in (-1,0) \end{cases}$
>
> Adding $1$ to both sides and dividing by $2$, we obtain both
>
> $\displaystyle f(x) = 1 \sim \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)^{-1}\sin \left( \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x \right)\, \implies \\ \begin{align} 2 \sim 1 +  \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)^{-1}\sin \left( \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x \right) \, \implies \\ 1 \sim \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)^{-1}\sin \left( \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x \right)\end{align} $
>
> -And-
>
> $\displaystyle -1 \sim \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)^{-1}\sin \left( \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi (x+1) \right)\, \implies \\ \begin{align} 0 \sim 1 +  \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)^{-1}\sin \left( \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi (x+1) \right) \, \implies \\ 0 \sim \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n-1)^{-1}\sin \left( \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi (x+1) \right)\end{align} $
>
> So, we have that
>
> $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n-1)^{-1}\sin\left[\left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x \right] = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in (0,1) \\ 0, & x \in (-1,0) \end{cases}$

---

The reason I'm not sure this answer is right is because of the $+ \frac{1}{2}$ term, which I've only seen happen in cases where we're trying to do a Fourier expansion in terms of even functions. But, is it the fact that $f(x) = 1$, which is even, the reason why the $+ \frac{1}{2}$ is appearing? Or did I make a mistake?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Would you care to explain why you downvoted?

Comment: Define the function $\tilde{f}(x) =\begin{cases} 1\quad \mbox{for}\quad 0<x < 1 \\ 0\quad \mbox{for}\quad -1<x<0 \end{cases}$ this is an odd extension of $f$. A Fourier series of $\tilde{f}$ will be your last equation. By doing it this way, you get for free the convergence of the series

Comment: @caverac cool! I feel better now!

Comment: Great! Happy to help

Comment: @caverac one of the things that was bothering me is that the definition of odd extension I've seen before is that if $f$ is piecewise continuous and defined on the interval $(0,a)$, then we can define the odd extension as $f_{\text{odd}}(x) = \begin{cases} -f(-x) & -a < x < 0 \\ f(x) & 0 < x < a\end{cases}\\$, so I thought that for $f(x) = 1$, the odd extension would be $f_{\text{odd}}(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & -1< x < 0 \\ 1 & 0 < x < 1\end{cases}\\$, and not  $f_{\text{odd}}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & -1< x < 0 \\ 1 & 0 < x < 1\end{cases}$, But, I just realized $f(x) = c$ is even for $c \neq 0$!

Comment: @caverac I'm going to edit my question to include an answer I came up with with the help of what Dr MV was saying. If you could let me know if it's correct or not, I'd appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: Sure, I'll have al ook

Comment: @caverac I just started a 100 point bounty on this question. If you take a look at what I did, and provide an answer, either saying it's correct, or providing a correct form of the answer, I will be glad to award it to you.

Comment: @caverac: If you want your extension to be odd, then for $-1<x<0$ you must put $\tilde f (x) = -1$, and also $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Your title of post is off topic because this site is not a discussion form.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay yes, please not be needlessly picky, and don't downvote me because you don't like the wording of my question title. I'll edit the title if you want to, but I didn't mean it in the term of a "discussion forum discussion". I am quoting verbatim the problem as it appears in my textbook.

Comment: @JessyCat, if you edit properly, I will remove my vote and also I will vote up if you edit it properly.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay I just did.

Comment: @AlexM. so from what you're saying to caverac, are you saying that my answer that I gave above isn't correct?

Comment: @JessyCat: You claim that $f(x) = c$ is even on $[-a,a]$, which is true. I am saying that $f(x) = \begin{cases} c, & 0 < x \le a \\ 0, & x = 0 \\ -c, & -a \le x < 0 \end{cases}$ is odd, which is again true. There is no contradiction between the two statements.

Comment: @JessyCat Will certainly have a look at it. Hope everything went ok with your assignment

Comment: @AlexM. You're right, but you can always subtract 1/2 and scale again, and the expansion will still be in $\sin$s. I apologize for the sloppy statement

Comment: @caverac actually, I got an extension and I'm still working on it ;)

Comment: @JessyCat Great, I posted my answer already. Please let me know what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your argument,

$$
\sin\left[(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi x\right] \ne - \sin\left[(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi (x + 1)\right]
$$

You can test that just by checking with $n = 1$:

- LHS:

  $$
   {\rm LHS} = \sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi x\right)
   $$
- RHS:

  $$
   {\rm RHS} = -\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi (x + 1)\right) = -\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi x + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = -\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi x\right) \ne {\rm LHS}
   $$

What you should do is realize that

$$
\sin\left[(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi (-x)\right] = -\sin\left[(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi x\right]
$$

therefore

$$
-1 \sim \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2n-1}\sin\left[(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi (-x)\right] ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ 0<x<1
$$

or equivalently

$$
-1 \sim \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2n-1}\sin\left[(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi x\right] ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ -1<x<0
$$

In summary you have

$$
\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2n-1}\sin\left[(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi x\right] \sim \begin{cases} 1, & 0 < x < 1 \\ - 1, & -1 < x < 0\end{cases}
$$

After this, you can definitely shift and scale as you did, reaching to the conclusion

$$
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2n-1}\sin\left[(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi x\right] \sim \begin{cases} 1, & 0 < x < 1 \\ 0, & -1 < x < 0\end{cases}
$$

Do not get confused by the $1/2$ term, it only gives you information about the average value of $f(x)$